# How to create a registration form and save the data on sqlite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am making an registration form in which i have two pages to complete the registration process.

page1 contains:

i have 8 textfield and one submit button in page 1...

when ever user enter the value in textfield and click the submit button all the enter value in textfield should get insert in my sqlite table and move to the next page with the same value in textfield .

page 2 contains

i have 8 textfield and two button:Edit, and continue in page 2...
this page should contains all the page1 textfield value in it,so that he can check the value enter by him are correct or not,and if not then he should be able to edit them and save them and proceed further.....

below is my page 1 code:
.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
#import "Confirmation_form.h"

@interface Registration_Form : 

UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> {
    Confirmation_form *con_form;

    sqlite3 *test1DB;

    IBOutlet UITextField *UserName;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Password;
    IBOutlet UITextField *ConfirmPassword;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Name;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Email;
    IBOutlet UITextField *ContactNO;
    IBOutlet UITextField *MobileNo;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Address;
    NSString *databasePath;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *UserName;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *Password;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *ConfirmPassword;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *Name;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *Email;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *ContactNO;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *MobileNo;

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *Address;


-(IBAction) submit;
```

**this is my .m file:**

```
#import "Registration_Form.h"


@implementation Registration_Form
@synthesize UserName,Password,ConfirmPassword,Name,Email,ContactNO,MobileNo,Address;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *docsDir;

    NSArray *dirPaths;


    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test1.db"]];


    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &test1DB) ==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;

            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, CONFIRMPASSWORD TEXT, NAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, CONTACTNO MUMBER, MOBILENO NUMBER,ADDRESS TEXT)";


            if(sqlite3_exec(test1DB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //status.text = @"Failed to create table";
            }
            sqlite3_close(test1DB);
        }else {
            //status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
        }

    }
    [filemgr release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(void)submit
{

sqlite3_stmt  *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &test1DB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO test(UserName, 

Password, ConfirmPassword, Name, Email, ContactNO, MobileNo, Address) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", 

\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",UserName.text, Password.text, ConfirmPassword.text, 

Name.text, Email.text, ContactNO.text, MobileNo.text, Address.text];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(test1DB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            //status.text = @"Contact added";
            UserName.text = @"";
            Password.text = @"";
            ConfirmPassword.text = @"";
            Name.text = @"";
            Email.text = @"";
            ContactNO.text = @"";
            MobileNo.text = @"";
            Address.text = @"";


        }else {
            //status.text = @"Failed to add Contact";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(test1DB);

    }

    con_form = [[Confirmation_form alloc] initWithNibName:@"Confirmation_form" bundle:[NSBundle 

mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:con_form animated:YES];

}
```

please help me out

thank's

Comment: Did you try this code? Were there any errors? What did the errors say?

Comment: this are my code...and i have tried this .....i am able to insert data in my database but i am not able to display the same data on to the next page...please help me out

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have create NSString object and their property  in your 1stcontroller than after  store the text filed value in this NSString .eg.passstring = UserName.text;

Than after pass this string to the next 2ndcontroller .

By creating the the object of 1stcontroller.like this 1stcontroller *urobject = [[1stcontroller  alloc]init];
yourtextfiled = urobject.passstring;

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Great tutorial on pure sqlite [here](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/).

But I would suggest just using properties unless that data is needed past the second form.

Also, if you are going to be doing a lot of db work I would suggest [FMDatabase](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).